# suggestions for staff id authentication

Tags: ipad

I'm developing an ipad app for managing HR attendance,

so the idea is that the staff come to the center, choose their name from a table, and write down their personal id, for the time they come and the time they leave,
still evaluating for the requirements if they want the time automatically saved or the staff write the time down (with a roller disk),  or both,

so what other way of authentication with an ipad comes to mind? (other than typing a code), (no ipad 2 wanted), so they don't want pictures. also how to avoid one person writing the code for a friend??,

the data will be stored in coredata, and sync with server,

thank you!

Comment: is this for a time keeping (ie, punch in, punch out type of thing) or time recording?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> also how to avoid one person writing
>   the code for a friend??

You can't unless you make the code something they don't want to share with their friend( their employee number and a pin for example that is connected to their ability to clock-in clock-out.  How many people are we talking about?  The simple solution is to place their picture on the badge, have enough people handing out badges, and only give a single badge per person.

How about simply making people sign a document?

Comment: How about using the SSN (of course, encrypted)...

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you want iPad, which hase no forward facing camera and runs iOS is quite limiting factor. There are plenty of secure solutions you could create using more open hardware. For example if you'd instead choose Android based tablet, you'd have possibility to use for example external fingerprint scanner.

---

Now given that you're not really concerned about true security of the system, there is simple, unintrusive solution that can be done using iPad 1. 
Although far from being 100% proof against friends signing in, you could associate ppl with their  phone's bluetooth MAC address. Than you could easily verify when they are close by (or rather their phone is). Of course this solution is far from being hack-proof, but there is no point in creating Fort Knox just for attendance tracking.

Comment: Depends on whether everybody's carrying phones with bluetooth enabled, and then you have to consider the case of MAC spoofing.

Comment: @David: rather then MAC spoofing I'd would worry about ppl bringing their friends phone. Anyway, given that this solution is to be based on iPad... I mean if you'd want secure system first of all you wouldn't base it on iPhone OS, you'd just connect $50 fingerprint scanner to a PC.

Comment: 180 hours of investment and a fingerprint scanner you can write a solution that can be cheated ( unless friends bring in their friend's fingers except that would make a mess ).

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm guessing you meant `s/can/can't/`; Anyway, for iOS? I wonder how you'd get it into App Store... unless of course you'd like to void your hardware's warranty by jail-breaking it.

Answer (score 1):

Try just using a paper sign in sheet. Really, if you don't trust people to be at work when they should be you probably shouldn't keep them around. (or hire them in the first place)